# Interpreting the likelihood estimate of transformed data

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, data-transformation

There is data $X(t)=[325200,500000,240000,130000,1200,10,10]$ where $t$ is time, $t=[0, 1 ,2 ,3,4,5,6]$ and I am fitting to these data assuming $X(t)$~Poisson$(X_0e^{\theta t})$ to estimate the parameter value of $\theta$. Data values $<=10$ are censored.

First, I log transformed the data so that $X'(t)=ln(X(t))$ and accordingly censoring was made for values less than or equal to $ln(10)$. Taking $X'(t)$~Poisson$(X'_0e^{\theta' t})$ and using the Poisson log likelihood function for censored data I found the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) for $\theta'$ as $-0.16$. The confidence interval around $\theta'$ was found to be $[-0.26,-0.08]$.

My question is how do I relate the MLE of the transformed data to the MLE that I would have obtained had I used the untransformed $(X(t))$ data?
Is the MLE of $\theta$ (the untransformed data)=$e^{(-0.16)}=0.8521$? But I expect $\theta$ to be negative.

Also, what is the confidence interval of the untransformed data will be?

Comment: (1) There must be something wrong with your estimation because the huge monotonic rate of decrease of $X(t)$ shows $\theta \gt 0$ but you quote negative values, which correspond to *increasing* $X(t)$! (2) Your two models are entirely different: an exponential decrease in $X(t)$ corresponds to a *linear* decrease in $\log(X(t)).$  Which model is the intended one?

Comment: @whuber  Sorry I made a mistake in typing. I fitted $X(t)$~Poisson $(X_0e^{\theta t})$. That's why a negative $\theta$ . I changed this in the post. So, if log transformation causes the entire model to change, can I at least scale the data as $X(t)/100$ and fit $X(t)$~Poisson $(X_0e^{\theta t})$? In this case how should the parameters be interpreted to non-scaled version? The reason I have to scale is, I am using a profile-likelihood approach to find the CIs and the large values of untransformed $X(t)$ is causing problems in calculating the log-likelihood values

Comment: The division by 10 appears to be arbitrary.  When the likelihoods are exceptionally low, suspect that the model might be poor.  It's difficult to suggest alternative models, knowing nothing about what the data mean.

Comment: @whuber $X(t)$ refers to a pathogen population that decrease over time as they are killed. When the pathogen count drops below 10 it is difficult to be observed. So the data below 10 are all reported as 10 (these points are censored)

Comment: A reasonable model would be to posit an additional iid error term $\epsilon(t)$ of unknown variance $\sigma^2$ so that $$X(t)\sim\text{Poisson}(\exp(\alpha -\theta t + \epsilon(t))$$ where $\alpha$ is a constant.  Although that requires estimating three parameters $\alpha,\theta,\sigma^2$ with only seven data values (and the last one provides essentially no additional information), it could give you *some* useful summary of the results. I believe that any GLM that can accommodate a random intercept $\alpha+\epsilon(t)$ would easily fit this model. You might have to modify it for censoring.

Comment: I'll add that I don't really believe the conditional response is Poisson: most likely the actual counts were *much* smaller and were multiplied up to estimate the total counts.  You need to use the *raw* counts that were observed.  The multipliers can be introduced as constant "offsets" into the model.